# How to get an email delivery acknowledgement using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails, I need to rectify which of my emails have been reached successfully to receiver's inbox. Is there any way to get the acknowledgement or delivery receipt for each email sent?

If possible I need those email id's inserted into my MySQL database.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I am not getting any specific logic to do it, now m just receiving the bounce emails on my webmail but dont knw any thing about the sent delivery report.

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to this, none of which are reliable.

You can request delivery receipts by adding the `Disposition-Notification-To` header. PHPMailer has built-in support for this:

```
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'confirmations@example.com';
```

Not many clients support this, and even if they do, it's likely they have it disabled for security reasons. Generally it's only likely to work within company intranets.

Secondly you can add an opening tracker or beacon image in your message body so that when a clint opens the message, the loading of the image tells you which message was opened. You need to embed a unique identifier for the recipient and/or the message in the URL, such as a hash of the email address and timestamp. Again, this is not reliable because most clients have image loading off by default, or the images may be opened by inbound mail scanners, giving you false positives.

The most effective way is really to get to know your mail server, and handle bounces correctly, but even then, just because a message has been devivered successfully to the recipient's mail server does not tell you whether it reached their inbox, nor whether it has been seen or opened.

Comment: Thanks Synchro This is fine for reading the mail, but i need the receipt for delivery, i need to know has my mail reached to the mailbox of the receiver.

Comment: I covered that, and as I said, you can never know this reliably.